# JQuery Function? Get an image to disappear when viewed in mobile and to only appear when it is viewed in larger screen sizes

Tags: jquery

I have placed an image in my theme HTML and it looks great in desktop view.

What I would like is to have the image hidden in the mobile view.

This is because the image is in the correct Div for larger screen sizes but incorrect for the smaller ones.

I believe the following may be the way forward, in this case;

```
JQuery function 

LAYOUT
Go to file: theme.liquid
ADD - {% include 'do-not-display-mobile' %}

SNIPPET
Create a snippet called: do-not-display-mobile
Add the following - 
{% comment %} 
Does no display in mobile-view conditions
{% endcomment %}

<a href="#" title="Do not display (Mobile)" class="do-not-display-mobile">

<style>
.do-not-display-mobile{
display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
 jQuery(function($) {   })
 });
}
</script>

Go to File:product-layout.liquid
Add to relevant elements: {% include 'do-not-display-mobile' %}
```

Then repeat for desktop-view.

UPDATE: I thought I needed a JQuery function ie IF screen width is <400px display none

But I do not know how to write the script, I used the answer below- by me.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the code you have tried?

Comment: No he cant Mr downvoter. cause he is new user and + what you want him to show you? in css about this question there is only two options. 1 you have heard about media CSS3 and so you know it can be done or you have not heard of it so you have no idea what you should do or even if its possible

Comment: Try to guide the new user instead of non-sense down-votes

Comment: @MishelParkour, I didn't downvote, but I don't think it is too much to ask to see the effort someone has put into a question especially when the question isn't complete. What screen size is the user targeting as mobile?

Comment: @DanielGale. Dear daniel im talking about guys who put down-votes and even don't care to put comments. So while it seems like i was talking to you actually i was talking to people who put down-votes, thinking that they are doing something usefull. but they are not they just lose points and destroy experience of a new user. And nothing useful will happen here. so you are a good one putting comments trying to guide

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean to be vague in my question.

Comment: <img style="margin-top:60px;" src="https://img>
{% if section.settings.social_sharing_products %}
{% include 'social-sharing', share_title: product.title, share_permalink: product.url, share_image: product %} {% endif %}
      </div>

Comment: This is the code I posted in the correct div for my site. However when I view it in mobile view it stays in the correct div but is in the wrong place for my viewers. So I wish to duplicate it for mobiles in the correct div, but add a code to each part of code to be hidden dependant on the type of view/screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one way of having different views and styles based on screen size is using CSS3 `@media` tag in you case the `max-with` and `min-with` will help you be able to have different looks based on screen size. Like changing background color or hiding a box or changing number of columns.

Here is a link : https://www.w3schools.com/cSS/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    body {
        background-color: lavender;
    }
}
```

So you should add css attributes to that element you want to appear or disappear in different screen sizes. And you need to have a selector to that element or div like how you select tags on css to give them styles

Comment: Apologies, I think I need a JQuery function this is where I am heading; LAYOUT
File: theme.liquid
{% include 'do-not-display-mobile' %}

SNIPPET
File: do-not-display-mobile
{% comment %} 
Does no display in mobile-view conditions
{% endcomment %}
<a href="#" title="Do not display (Mobile)" class="do-not-display-mobile">
 <style>
.do-not-display-mobile{
display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
 jQuery(function($) {   })
 });
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are referring to the basics of Responsive Web Design: different markups for different screen resolutions or types.

My preferred method is a combination of HTML5 and CSS3.

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <img class="desktop" src="/dt_image.png">
   <img class="mobile" src="/mb_image.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img.desktop {
    display: block;
}
img.mobile {
    /* Hide mobile version */
    display: none;
}

/* Mobile breakpoint */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320 px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    img.desktop {
        /* Hide desktop version */
        display: none;
    }
    img.mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Of course this also gives you the freedom and possibilities to define widths, and other attributes per image within your div.

Comment: Product-template.liquid
 </div>
  <img style="margin-top:60px;" src="https://.png"/img>      
{% if section.settings.social_sharing_products %}
{% include 'social-sharing', share_title: product.title, share_permalink: product.url, share_image: product %}{% endif %}
 </div>

Comment: Do I need to add the CSS to the theme.scss.liquid or the timber.scss.liquid? Then place class to the image?

Comment: @media, not sure on this part, do I need to create a snippet

Comment: Apologies, I think I need a JQuery function this is where I am heading; LAYOUT
File: theme.liquid
{% include 'do-not-display-mobile' %}

SNIPPET
File: do-not-display-mobile
{% comment %} 
Does no display in mobile-view conditions
{% endcomment %}
<a href="#" title="Do not display (Mobile)" class="do-not-display-mobile">
 <style>
.do-not-display-mobile{
display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
 jQuery(function($) {   })
 });
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are referring to the basics of Responsive Web Design: different markups for different screen resolutions or types.

My preferred method is a combination of HTML5 and CSS3.

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <img class="desktop" src="/dt_image.png">
   <img class="mobile" src="/mb_image.png">
</div>
```

**CSS (inside HTML sheet)**

```
<style>
img {
    margin-top: 60px;
}   

img.desktop {
    display: block;
}
img.mobile {
    /* Hide mobile version */
    display: none;
}

/* Mobile breakpoint */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320 px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    img.desktop {
        /* Hide desktop version */
        display: none;
    }
    img.mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>
```

Of course this also gives you the freedom and possibilities to define widths, and other attributes per image within your div.